# How to Use Selenium to select the value of “style”

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want building test plan for page that contain button which open small color selection  window.![enter image description here][1]

the color window is divided to 2 parts , this is the code of the right panel:

```
<span class="ui-colorpicker-bar-layer-pointer">  
<span class="ui-colorpicker-bar-pointer" style="top: 51.0333px;"></span>
```

the question is what i need to write (selenium webdriver - java) 
after the color window appear , for select the color ( how i select the style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use `getAttribute()` to retrieve the style from a web element:

```
string elementStyle = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-colorpicker-bar-pointer")).getAttribute("style");
```

Comment: definitely difficult to understand what they are asking, but I believe you are on the right track. +1

Answer (score 0):

i did  retrieve the style from the web element,
but i am trying to set new style  , i tried this:

```
      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
           js.executeScript("document.getElementById('colorPickIcon').setAttribute('style', '22.3333px')");
```

and it doesn't work....